# mysql - setting datetime field to only a day or certain hour

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL,
I have two datetime fields. One for the actual date which I know how it works. 
And the other I would like to hold the interval. For example 5 hours or 5 days. How would I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if understand rightly, use the **INTERVAL**

```
mysql> SELECT something FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY) <= date_col;
```

Refer this link: [**OfficalSite**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)